# Monte Carlo simulation of task completion times

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Assume a task T has minimum time of 8 days to complete, maximum time of 14 days, and a most likely time of 10 days (mode). The standard deviation is 1.00 ($\frac{Max-Min}{6}$) and mean is 10.3333 ($\frac{Min+4\times MostLikely+Max}{6}$) according to PERT in a beta distribution.

I want to model this with basic Excel functions and then randomly generate many simulated actual T completion times.

Let's say in a single iteration, I randomly generate an actual task completion time of 11 days. Do I simply convert this into a probability? How?

Can I assume a normal distribution and then use Excel's `NORM.DIST` formula?

I'm having trouble framing the question the right way. For example, let's say in another iteration, the actual completion time was 14 days (which was the estimated maximum time possible for T). If I used `NORM.DIST(x=14, mean=10, standard_dev=10.33, cumulative=1)`, I get 0.6507, which I don't understand. Shouldn't it be 100% that all completion times are 14 or lower? In other words, I can't work out the intuition for framing the question properly.

Comment: It _is not possible_ for any probability distribution to have its entire probability mass in the interval $[8,14]$ and yet have a standard deviation as large as $10.3$. Something must be wrong with your assumptions at the top.

Comment: Oops, yes, I corrected the question. Also, I discovered the `BETA.DIST` formula in Excel, although I still don't have the intuition to be confident of applying it correctly.

Comment: If your goal is to generate a list of task times you should be using BETAINV with the parameters you derive. You should note that the beta distribution generates numbers from 0 to 1 so you will need to next scale (multiply by max-min) and shift (add the min) to get a scenario.